# react profile component how to aggregate times

Tags: reactjs, profiler

I am trying to measure a webpage loading time (react app). I found out there is `React.Profiler` component to use. I think sum of all `commitTime - startTime` will give me the page loading time. I think it's safe to use just a variable to collect the total time because I don't want state due to infinite rerender. Then, how can I find out the last update of the component so that I can send the total loading time to another service or store in db?

```
function Profile({children}) {
  let total = 0;
  function onRender(id, phase, actualDuration, baseDuration, startTime, commitTime) {
    total += commitTime - startTime);
  }

  return (
    <Profiler id="loadingtime">
      {children}
    </Profiler>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) be what you're looking for?

Comment: could you elaborate more? how can you use ```useRef()``` to find out the last render?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought you just wanted to store `total`. The way it's currently setup, `total` is assigned 0 on every render.

Comment: yeah I think that's my intention because I want to measure page loading time which is just the first render. but since children will also render, I want to find out the last render so I can find out page loading time